# Filebeat docker multiline

Tags: linux, debian, elasticsearch, filebeat

I'm using filebeat to retrieve log files to Elastic cloud. I'd like to put errors and java exception in one document instead of multiple for each line. I managed to make it work on text log files but it does not seem to work on containers logs.

Here's the configuration for docker on my filebeat.yml :

```
...
filebeat.inputs:
- type: container
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - '/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log'
  pipeline: docker
  parsers:
  - multiline:
      type: pattern
      pattern: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
      negate: true
      match: after
...
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata:
      host: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
  - decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["message"]
      target: "json"
      overwrite_keys: true
```

A usual log message would look like this :

```
2023-05-10 10:18:31.990 INFO 1 --- XXXX
```